# The importance between of the difference of the proton and neutron electromagnetic structure functions $_$

Tags: nuclear-physics, neutrons, protons

There is a famous momentum sum rule given by Gottfried, where the sum rule can be violated considering the flavor of $\bar u$ and $\bar d$ are not symmetric. The violation was proved by one experiment called NMC.

My question is that how do you describe the electromagnetic structure function $S_G$ and why it is important quantifying $S_G$ ? Could you give me some info with some reference that what exactly is the $S_G$ (I know that it is the difference between proton and neutron electromagnetic structure function)?

The relationship can be written:

$$S_G = \int_0^x\frac{dx}{x}(F_2^p -F_2^n)$$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Note that the number of quarks and antiquarks at $Q^2$ is:

$$ N_{q\bar q} = \int{\frac{dx} x F_2(x)} \approx \sum{\int{(q_i(x)+\bar q_i(x))dx}}$$

so the Gottfried Sum Rule is the difference in the number of quarks and antiquarks in the proton and neutron, with the appropriate charge weighting. Using isospin symmetry gives:

$$S_G = \int_0^1{\frac{dx} x [\frac 4 9 (u(x)+\bar u(x)) + \frac 1 9(d(x)+\bar d(x) ) -\frac 1 9 (u(x)+\bar u(x)) - \frac 4 9(d(x)+\bar d(x) ) ]} $$

$$ S_G = \frac 1 3 \int_0^1{\frac{dx} x[u(x)-d(x)+\bar u(x)-\bar d(x) ]}\\=\frac 1 3 + \frac 1 3 [\bar u(x)-\bar d(x)]$$

The NMC data are:
[image]

Comment: Could you please do one more line of integration that how you got $$ S_G = \frac 1 3 + \frac 1 3 [\bar u(x)-\bar d(x)]$$? 

Is it because the momentum fraction of u, quarks are 3 times than d quarks?

Comment: I think it was mostly because, proton holds two up quarks and one down quarks. :)